# Tcl info exists

Tags: tcl

I have a curious case of Tcl that perhaps I just don't understand.
The following code is done at the top level (not inside of any procedure):

```
if {![info exists g_log_file_name]} {
    set g_log_file_name "default.txt"
}
```

What I hope it would do is to declare a global variable with some value if it wasn't declared yet (which can be done at some other script or C application). However, the if statement *always* false. I ran on Tcl 7.4.

What may be the problem?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
% info level
0
% info exists g_log_file_name
0
% set g_log_file_name whatever
whatever
% info exists g_log_file_name
1
```

Hence the reason you observe is probably because the variable is really *always* unset at the time your `if` command is executed.

Possible reasons for this I can imagine are:

- It's just not set: literally, no code attempt to do this;
- The external code sets some other variable: name mismatch;
- The external code sets a variable in some other interpreter: in a C code embedding Tcl, there can be any number of Tcl interpreters active at any moment (and those are free to create child interpreters as well);

I'm not sure abot the long forgotten version of Tcl you have at hand, but 8.x has the [`trace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/trace.htm) command which can be used to log accesses to a particular variable—you could try to use it to see what happens.

Comment: There was variable tracing in 7.4 (it's key machinery for Tk) though it's the old-style syntax. (Command and execution tracing are much later additions.)